# Determinant Algebra question; finding a determinant based on other matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

[image: Problem]!

First part was very simple, second part though I've been wrking on it and am still confused.

Okay now let me start by saying that I know all the rules for determinant algebra (I think). The thing is that I see a fundamental issue here in that I think I need to add the matrices together but from what I know, there isn't a good formula for finding a determinant through matrix addition. The other option is to multiple rows but then the variables would have coefficients

I have decided that I could always just use one of the matrices and pull out the algebra for finding its determinant, and then use the relation of a b c d e f to find the determinant of the final matrix. But I think that would be missing the point of the problem no?

So I think I know how to get the answer but I think it'd be the wrong way of getting it, if that makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: I just read on the meta page that homework questions aren't allowed anymore. Should I make my own problem then and post it here for a more general discussion/tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determinants are multilinear functions of their column vectors (and its row vectors, too, BTW, but you need to consider column vectors here).  So say you have $\det(\mathbf a, \mathbf b, \mathbf c)=u$ and $\det(\mathbf a, \mathbf d, \mathbf c)=v$ and you'd like to find $\det(\mathbf a, \mathbf e, \mathbf c)$, where $\mathbf e=\beta \mathbf b + \delta \mathbf d$.  Then $\det(\mathbf a, \mathbf e, \mathbf c) = \beta\det(\mathbf a, \mathbf b, \mathbf c)+\delta \det(\mathbf a, \mathbf d, \mathbf c)=\beta u + \delta v$ by the linearity of the 2nd argument of the $\det$ function.

So you just need to check if $(1,-1,-3) \in \operatorname{span}\left((1,1,1),(1,2,3)\right)$ -- it is -- and then find the linear combination of $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,2,3)$ which gives you $(1,-1,-3)$.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realized that addition of columns from different matrices worked like that.. I tried to use google to figure that out but I came up empty I thought. So I just need to find the coefficients of the linear combination (i forget the name for this vector off the top of my head). Thank you, upvoted.